# How can I return json data and then stop the corresponding action in my custom filter attribution ? 

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

There is an asynchronous request that need authorize user. I want to authorize in filter attribution. If user can't login, return a json data that used to tell the client to callback a javascript function  to popup the login window.
how can I stop the action in filter attribution?

Comment: Can you provide some code please? So we can see what you've done so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom `ActionFilterAttribute`. Override `OnActionExecuting`.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new EmptyResult();
        return;
    }

    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

Instead of `EmptyResult` return whatever you want.